# Resampling an array of objects

Tags: algorithms, sampling

#### Context

I have an array of objects (or a list of dictionaries), sorted in order based on a property of each object, say, `time`.  In JSON, it would look something like this:

```json
[
  {'details': 'some details', 'time': 69},
  {'details': 'some details', 'time': 79},
  {'details': 'some details', 'time': 107},
  {'details': 'some details', 'time': 339},
  {'details': 'some details', 'time': 339},
  {'details': 'some details', 'time': 344},
  ...
]
```

Each entry represents the state of my program at a certain point in time.  The entries are in order, but are *not* spaced evenly across time.  A nice visual along a numberline representing time might look like this:

[image]

So we have a series of objects called snapshots ($S_n$) along a timeline, whose time values place them unevenly across time.

#### The goal

I want to resample these snapshot objects such that I produce a new array of snapshot objects, but spaced evenly across time.  A quick visual would look like this:

[image]

Here you can see a resampled timeline, where resampled snapshots $R$ correspond to the *latest available snapshot $S$ that has occured at or before a time corresponding to $R_n$*.  By definition, $R_0$ is always set to be the same as $S_0$, as it is the starting point for both unevenly and evenly snapshots.

#### Thinking through some details

There are two cases we need to account for - (1) when there are more than 1 $S$ between $R$s, and (2) when there are no new $S$s between $R$s.  The following image demonstates both scenarios:

[image]

We see that for $R_1$, several $S$s have passed, so we skip them, and $R_1$'s sample returns $S_2$ (scenario 1).  For $R_2$, no new $S$s have occurred, so the state of the application based on the information we have is still at $S_2$, and $R_2$ samples at $S_2$ as well.  Perhaps this is already obvious from the above description.

#### Writing a function?

I have been thinking about this for some time, and I have been trying to bang out a function to perform this sampling given an array of snapshots $A_S$ and a sampling interval $I$.  I would like to make it as efficient as possible.  My thoughts were to make a copy of $A_S$ (so as not to mutate the original) called $C_S$, and then begin popping snapshots from the front of $C_S$.  This way, for every $R$ we establish, we continue working from what remains of $C_S$, thus reducing the number of iterations we have to make through the original snapshots and increasing the efficiency of the algorithm.

I am struggling to come up with such a function, and given what a simple concept this is, I wonder if it already exists somewhere?  I need to implement this in TypeScript/Javascript, but a solution in python or pseudocode would also be very helpful, or even a link to "hey, this is a common problem that is already described / solved."

Comment: Hello at COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. `I wonder if it already exists somewhere?` I think *wondering* legitimate. Just consider where *revisiting past material* and *trying problem solving techniques* gets you, and where *having something or somebody else find a solution*. Coding (and most programming) questions are off-topic [*here*](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). See [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-cs-site?r=SearchResults&s=2|351.0732)

Comment: (`The goal` sketches a required output - just walking the array should easily produce that. I suggest to explicitly state "everything" else required.)

Comment: I had originally posted this question on the computational science SE, but someone there suggested I post it here.  Considering this is a language agnostic question, and fits the description of "if your question calls for abstract/mathematical models and reasoning", I thought this might be the right place.  I know that 'walking the array' will be involved, but I;m trying to figure out the most efficient way to do that so as not to waste any computational power.

Comment: ([Sampling rings a bell](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(audio)).) If not taking the input samples as a presentation of a continuous signal, consider [exponential/"galloping" search](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) for the sub-problem of finding, for a given re-sample point, samples with close time stamps. Another idea is to use "past experience of gap size" for an educated guess about the current one. Your example feature non-unique time stamps - loads of those can ruin "everything".